# How to catch hash change in Python?

Tags: python, file, hash

My goal is program, that catches hash changes in all files of the folder and prints the message about certain file being changed (so the hash is changed also), but I dont understand, how to catch that change. Currently my program analizes and shows all files` hashes in the folder every 10 seconds.

```
import glob
import hashlib
import threading

filenames = glob.glob("D:/Downloads/*")

def blake2s (fname):
    hash_blake2s = hashlib.blake2s()
    with open(fname, "rb") as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
            hash_blake2s.update(chunk)
    return hash_blake2s.hexdigest()

def print_hashes():
    threading.Timer(10.0, print_hashes).start()
    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename, "\t\t", blake2s(filename))
    print ("")

print_hashes()
```

Comment: You will need a way to store the original hash of each file.

Comment: What you have just prints the hash without saving it. So your program has absolutely no idea what the hash was 10 seconds before for it to know if the hash of the file has changed. Ideally, you would want to maintain a map that maps every file to its hash at time t = 0. So at time t=10, when you recompute the hash again, you can check it with the already stored value for that file and see if it is different. If you see it is not the same as the map, then you know the hash has changed and you can do whatever needs to be done.

Comment: "Hash change" is virtually synonymous with "file change", as it is highly unlikely you are going to see a file change that *doesn't* change the hash. Take a look at https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/, which is going to be more efficient than recalculating hashes for every file every 10 seconds.